# Browse Mobile Websites From Desktop/Laptop

Tags: browser

Is it possible to browse the internet from a laptop so that the web sites you visit think you are browsing from a mobile device?

Say I need to connect via a very low bandwidth connection and just using the mobile version of the site is sufficient?

Currently I'm using Vista and Firefox 3.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download the firefox plugin [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59). This will allow you to spoof any user agent you please. You can choose a user agent from [this](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html) page. If you wanted to appear to be using an iPhone, you could enter something like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac
>   OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a
>   Safari/419.3

Comment: I would vote this one up but no reputation! The User Agent Switcher is just the ticket..! Awesome.

Comment: Have some rep Dog ears +1

Comment: +1, but don't forget **general.useragent.override** in `about:config` if you don't want to install yet another addon.
Also, if the site uses WAP/WML instead of HTML, the Opera browser might be able to open it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an emulator, to emulate a mobile device.

For example from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A6F6ADAF-12E3-4B2F-A394-356E2C2FB114&displaylang=en) or [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, if you turn the develop menu on in safari you can set the user agent string to Mobile safari 3.0 and Volia you are pretending you are an iPhone.

Another way is to use the windows CE Emulator that comes with visual studio and use mobile IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["Web Developer Toolbar"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) to simulate mobile screen sizes and you can use "User Agent Switcher"  to switch to a mobile user agent as mentioned above.