# How can I treat *one* tab on desktop browser as mobile?

Tags: firefox, browser

I want to be able to run two tabs of the same website, *in the same browser, at the same time*.  The first tab should act normally and receive desktop versions.  The second tab would be treated as a mobile browser and receive mobile versions.

How can I do this?

**Edit**

Apparently I've done a poor job asking.  I want to know how I can have a single browser window with two tabs.  The first tab uses the desktop version, the second uses the mobile version.  Hopefully the screenshot below can help illustrate.

[image: Example]

Comment: This is not a dupe of [this question](http://superuser.com/q/11321/210293).  I am not asking how I can force my browser to emulate a mobile device.  I am asking how I can force a *single tab* to emulate a mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox cannot easily do this without using a plugin of some sort such as Firebug.  If you're not tied to Firefox, this is very easily done in Chrome using the built in Developer Tools.  They include an Emulator tab which allows you to select a device (mobile or tablet) to emulate.  It's not a perfect representation, but it will make the website believe you are the emulated device.

Comment: Can you explain how to get to the emulation section?  I'm not seeing the option in the Developer Tools.

Comment: With the Developer Tools open, depending on the layout, you may need to click a button in the top right of the developer tools that highlights as Open Drawer.  Click this button if the drawer is not open.  In the drawer, you'll see 4 tabs: Console, Search, Emulation and Rendering.  Click the Emulation tab.  The select the device and click Emulate.  The browser tab you last selected when you opened the Developer Tools will now emulate that device

Answer (score 2):

Firefox provides feature `Responsive Design View` to view how websites look on different screen sized devices such as mobile phone and tablets.
Check on Firefox developers guide [Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View)

To activate Resposive Design View use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Is there an api for this option ? For enabling it through js code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably look at UserAgent switchers, possibly [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)  Depending on how the website detects "Mobile" you may need to alter other Client Request headers, maybe the screen size header.

You may want to [check the user agent string](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/) of your mobile browser, to be able to clone it effectively.

One Caveat that there may be assumptions for mobile, such as that you're on a small screen on mobile, and it will look horrible on a desktop size screen.  Try it, let us know :).

Comment: This add-on will alter the entire browser.  I was hoping to find one that is per-tab.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on how you have separated your desktop content from mobile content on the server-side.

- Are you using `www.example.com` and `mobile.example.com`?
- Are you using media queries within your CSS?
- Are you simply loading `style.css` and `mobile.style.css` conditionally?